# Maximum value of $\frac{ab+bc+cd+de}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I had asked a similar question a few days back.

[Maximum value of expression: $\frac{ab+bc+cd}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192095/maximum-value-of-expression-fracabbccda2b2c2d2/2192137#2192137)

I want to know if a similar expression,  $\frac{ab+bc+cd+de}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2}$ could have a bound, and if it does, how we can find it.

Comment: It seems like [M. Boyet's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192104/2785) to your previous question works in this case too.

Comment: are $$a,b,c,d,e$$ real numbers? or positives?

Comment: Sonnhard  It does not change nothing!

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard, I'm not sure, but can you tell my why it matters if the numbers are positive numbers or just some real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You may easily recognize the norm of a linear operator, $v\mapsto Mv$, where

$$ M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
is a Toeplitz matrix with eigenvalues $0$, $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and $\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It follows that $\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ is an optimal upper bound, achieved by $(a,b,c,d,e)=\lambda(1, \sqrt 3, 2, \sqrt 3, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-\frac{2}{\sqrt3}(ab+bc+cd+de)=$$
$$=a^2-\frac{2ab}{\sqrt3}+\frac{b^2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}b^2-\frac{2bc}{\sqrt3}+\frac{c^2}{2}+\frac{c^2}{2}-\frac{2cd}{\sqrt3}+\frac{2d^2}{3}+\frac{d^2}{3}-\frac{2de}{\sqrt3}+e^2=$$
$$=\left(a-\frac{b}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}b-\frac{c}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt2}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}d\right)^2+\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt3}-e\right)^2\geq0.$$
Hence, $\frac{ab+bc+cd+de}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and it's obvious that the equality occurs, which gives the answer:
$$\max\frac{ab+bc+cd+de}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}.$$
Done!

Comment: Can you tell.me how you just landed up with the first expression? It doesn't look intuitive why you started with $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ in the start.

Comment: @HariPrasad Poilath We can start with $k$ and we can try to use the same thing, which you saw. Finely we'll get equation with variable $k$.